# MVC6 and Microsoft Identity Deployment

Tags: model-view-controller, web-deployment, identity, asp.net-identity-2

I'm looking at creating a new project that would have users with profiles. I have not worked with Microsoft Identity before and have a few questions:

1. If you are using Microsoft Identity with MVC6, are you still able to deploy/host on Linux machines?
2. Is there any associated costs with using Identity in production (e.g. licensing costs)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question...

1. Yes, Identities will work cross platform when deployed to the new DNX cross platform target.
2. No, there are no direct licensing costs with building a .Net application that uses Identities.